# Complex Select with 3 Tables

Tags: php, sql, filter, e-commerce, product

I am working on ecommerce app, and I am struggling with selecting product properties to use them as filters.

There are 3 tables:

**product**

| id | name | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Balloon XL Red | 1 |
| 2 | Balloon L Red | 1 |
| 3 | Balloon XL Green | 1 |
| 4 | Balloon S Green | 1 |
| 5 | Balloon XL Black | 1 |

**property**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Color |
| 2 | Size |

**propertyvalue**

| id | property | product | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Red |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | XL |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | Red |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | L |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | Green |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | XL |
| 7 | 1 | 4 | Green |
| 8 | 2 | 4 | S |
| 9 | 1 | 5 | Black |
| 10 | 2 | 5 | XL |

Demo is available on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c5255)

First of all I create an array of all available properties to let users filter products.

```
SELECT * FROM property
```

And then I get distinct values for each of the properties

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM propertyvalue
WHERE property = 1
```

As a result I get this array of all properties and their distinct values:

Size:

- XL
- L
- S

Color:

- Red
- Green
- Black

Lets say, user filters products by Property 'Color' = 'Black' OR 'Color' = 'Red'

```
SELECT * FROM product
INNER JOIN propertyvalue
ON product.id = propertyvalue.product
WHERE
    (
        propertyvalue.value = 'Black' AND propertyvalue.property = 1
        OR
        propertyvalue.value = 'Red' AND propertyvalue.property = 1
    )
    AND product.active = 1
```

As a result we get 2 products with XL and L sizes.
How do I update Size list, to display only XL and L size, since there are no products with S size?

```
SELECT * FROM propertyvalue
?????
WHERE propertyvalue.property = 2
```

I am using PHP as backend. Happy to answer any aditional questions. Help.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT value FROM ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: You already have a query that gets distinct sizes. Seems like you would simply need to expand on it to use the same conditions as your filtering query.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to run another query, you could create an array of unique sizes while you're iterating the filtered results in PHP.

Comment: @El_Vanja I am strugling to grasp what that query should look like. I am not iterating over all results, LIMIT is set to 15

Comment: Can you post the actual output of the query under question? The descriptive sentence doesn't match the data and the query.

Comment: Side note: having properties in a separate table adds unnecessary complexity and makes your queries more difficult to understand. Do you have any influence over the schema? If so, I'd make `size` and `color` direct columns of the `products` table.

Comment: @El_Vanja it is impossible, there are hundreds of properties and thousands of products

Comment: @k_rus I am not sure I understand you correctly. You can try any queries at demo page http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c5255/16

Comment: @torasko It is great that I can follow the link and try there, however questions in Stackoverflow are expected to be complete without need to go by the link to get necessary information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize a subquery:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT pv.value FROM propertyvalue pv
INNER JOIN product p ON p.id = pv.product
WHERE pv.property = 2 AND p.id IN (
    SELECT product.id FROM product
    INNER JOIN propertyvalue
    ON product.id = propertyvalue.product
    WHERE
    (
        propertyvalue.value = 'Black' AND propertyvalue.property = 1
        OR
        propertyvalue.value = 'Red' AND propertyvalue.property = 1
    )
    AND product.active = 1
)
```

Basically, the subquery is the same as your product filtering query, with the only difference being that it's selecting just the product ids instead of everything. This way, no matter how complex that query might be (you mentioned hundreds of properties in the comments), you can always wrap that logic with a statement like this and extract some unique values from that specific subset.

Comment: Vanja, thank you very much! I really appretiate your help. I'm already working on implementing your query in production code.